# Laravel Project Folder Location Apache

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5

I created a new laravel project in `/var/www/html/project` with:

```
cd /var/www/html
laravel new project
```

My apache config file has the following:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project/public"
...
<Directory "/var/www/html/project/public">
```

When I go to my website homepage I don't see the welcome page. Shouldn't this default route `/var/www/html/project/app/Http/routes.php` return the welcome page? What am I missing in the apache config file?

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give some `files permission`

> **Directory Permissions** After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set. [#Laravel Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)

You need to give `storage` writable permissions.

```
sudo chgrp www-data -R bootstrap/cache storage
sudo chmod g+w -R bootstrap/cache storage
```

Answer (score 0):

you should access `yousitePath/public/(your route)`.

Comment: Edited the DocumentRoot above to the appropriate one and still no luck

Comment: Keep the default configuration for the document and directory, and access the url i've proposed. Does it work?

Comment: `http://www.example.com/project/public/index.php` does not work error 500. `http://www.example.com/project/public/a1.php` (a file I created) does work. The routes do not though

Comment: index.php should be the single access point for your application in laravel. If you want to visit the home page, it should just be http://www.example.com/ in your browser. I would check to see which sites are enabled on the server to make sure it is available. If you haven't already, you may need to restart apache.